# Can't install Unity after Hub froze during installation - where to find Unity files and delete them?

Tags: unity, windows

I'm struggling to reinstall Unity after Hub crashed halfway through installing an editor version.

I have tried to delete the partially installed Unity - but I don't know all the locations to look, as any new attempts to load Unity are blocked by older files.

[image: Error dialog: Unity 2021.1.16f1 Android Support Setup: Failed to delete old Unity Android Support installation files. Maybe Unity or some of its tools are still running?]

There is no Unity running. I checked in Task Manager. I had made sure the directory was empty before I reinstalled. I also restarted the Hub before I started the new installation (just in case) then removed Hub, and after that all Unity versions....

Running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Press the Locate button on the Installs tab of the hub.
[image]

That will bring up a folder showing the install path of the editors.
[image]

Comment: Hub showed nothing, but saw partial folder in the HubEditor, also a problem with connecting android. Reinstalled Unity + android tools but I Hub faild to find sdk's which I thought Hub would do

Console
1) CommandWithNoStdoutInvokationFailure: Gradle initialization failed.
2) The option setting android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
3) WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
4) PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
5) > C:\Users\bb\.gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by folder permissions, which needed to be changed on the `.bin` file. The old file couldn't be overwritten. Here is the console output I was getting during an installation attempt:

```
CommandWithNoStdoutInvokationFailure: Gradle initialization failed.
The option setting android.enableR8=false' is deprecated. 
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
C:\Users\bb\.gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)
```

Unchecking the read-only permissions checkbox on last-build.bin fixed all the other problems, and my game is running now on Android.